# select and count rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables and I need to select and count rows in one query, maybe somebody can help me with that, my query is:

```
SELECT
    c.id, c.first_name, c.last_name, c.speciality, c.level, c.email, c.skype, c.city, 
    s.status_type, c.status_id, c.linkedin, c.link_cv, c.interview_res, c.createdAt,
    c.updatedAt, c.recruiter_id, u.first_name AS fname, u.last_name AS lname
FROM
    Candidates c
    JOIN Users u 
        ON c.recruiter_id = u.id
    JOIN Statuses s
        ON s.id = c.status_id
WHERE
    c.deleted = false
```

and I need to get count of the rows that respond my select and count them.

example output (what I want):

```
count | fname  | lname  | ..... |
---------------------------------
3     | Ihor   | Shmidt | ...   |
3     | Andre  | Agassi | ....  |
3     | Roger  | Federer| ..... |
```

i.e. I want to have my fields that I select and their count

Comment: What exactly do you need a count of? Can you please add an example of the expected output?

Comment: count of rows that respond condition "c.deleted = false" , in output it shoukld look like: (row1) first_name - Ihor, last_name - Shmidt, ... count(2), row(2) Andre, Agassi... count(2)

Comment: your requirement is not clear. Please add a sample of desired results you want to see in your question.

Comment: i added description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

COUNT(*) as count or COUNT(c.id) as count

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as count,c.id, c.first_name, c.last_name, c.speciality, c.level, c.email,
    c.skype, c.city, s.status_type, c.status_id, c.linkedin, c.link_cv, c.interview_res,
    c.createdAt, c.updatedAt, c.recruiter_id, u.first_name AS fname, u.last_name AS lname 
  FROM Candidates c 
  JOIN Users u
    ON c.recruiter_id = u.id
  JOIN Statuses s
    ON s.id = c.status_id
  WHERE c.deleted = false;
```

Comment: in this case it`s only returns one row, but i need all rows and their count

Comment: Ok,I understand what do you need.
Try next

Comment: it has same result

Comment: Ok,I understand what do you need.
Try next.  GROUP BY c.id .

Use it at the end of the code


  SELECT COUNT(*) as count,c.id .... ... WHERE c.deleted = false  

    GROUP BY c.id

Comment: in this case it`s returns all rows and one column where repeat`s number "1"

Comment: try this
SELECT 
  c.id,
  (
    SELECT COUNT(*)  FROM Candidates c 
       JOIN Users u
       ON c.recruiter_id = u.id
      JOIN Statuses s
     ON s.id = c.status_id
  WHERE c.deleted = false
)  AS `count` ....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114474/discussion-between-ihor-sh-and-vanya-avchyan).

Answer (score 1):

Before the "from" portion of the query, please add count (*). It will give you the count of the rows.

```
Select ......, count (*) from Candidates c 
JOIN Users u ON c.recruiter_id = u.id 
JOIN Statuses s on s.id = c.status_id
WHERE c.deleted = false;
```

Comment: in this case it`s only returns one row, but i need all rows and their count (

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT c.id, ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Candidates c 
JOIN Users u ON c.recruiter_id = u.id 
JOIN Statuses s ON s.id = c.status_id 
WHERE c.deleted = false ) AS count  FROM Candidates 
c JOIN Users u ON c.recruiter_id = u.id 
JOIN Statuses s ON s.id = c.status_id 
WHERE c.deleted = false ;
```