# SELECT only rows when count=1 - without additional SELECT or/ and having

Tags: sql, sql-server, etl

I wonder if there is a way to build a query without joins or/and having clause that would return the same result as  the query below? I already found similar question ([select and count rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37777184/select-and-count-rows)) but didn't find the answer.

```
SELECT ID, CATEGORY, PRODUCT, DESC
    FROM SALES s
    JOIN (SELECT ID, COUNT(CATEGORY)
        FROM SALES
        GROUP by ID
        HAVING count(CATEGORY)=1) S2 ON S.ID=S2.ID;
```

So the table looks like

```
ID | Country  | Product  | DESC 
1  | USA      | Cream    | Super cream
1  | Canada   | Toothpaste| Great Toothpaste
2  | Germany  | Beer     | Tasty Beer
```

and the result I would like to get is

```
ID | Country  | Product  | DESC 
2  | Germany  | Beer     | Tasty Beer
```

because id=1 has 2 different countries assigned

I'm using SQL Server

In general I'm interested in the 'fastest' solution. The table is huge and I just wonder if there is a way to do it smarter.

Comment: update your question  .. add  a proper data sample and the expected  result

Comment: Please provide expected results.

Comment: add an alias to the count column and simply add a `where S2.CNT = 1`

Comment: What is your particular SQL database?  (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, Postgres, DB2, etc.). If you're using MySQL, then please tell us which _version_ you are using.

Comment: Thanks a lot for comments, I added needed info

Comment: Why is "without joins or/and having clause" a requirement? Bear in mind that with SQL, you're telling the system *what you want*, not *how to do it*. It's the optimizer that then works out how best to compute the result. In turn, this means that any two queries that *logically* represent the same operation should (if the optimizer isn't having a bad day and you haven't gone out of your way to obfuscate the meaning) produce the *same plan*.

Comment: yes, you are right. Probably my question should be how to do it differently to increase performance.

Answer (score 0):

you may want to consider this query.

```
select t2.id, t2.category, t2.product, t2.desc from (
    select id, category, product,
        case when (select count(1) from sales where id=t1.id group by id) as ct
        ,desc
    from sales t1) t2 where t2.ct = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this Query:

```
SELECT ID, CATEGORY, PRODUCT, DESC
FROM SALES s
WHERE 1 = (
  SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM SALES x
  WHERE x.ID = s.ID
);
```

Answer (score 0):

One method uses window functions:

```
SELECT ID, CATEGORY, PRODUCT, DESC
FROM (SELECT s.*, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY ID) as cnt
      FROM SALES s
     ) s
WHERE cnt = 1;
```

However, the fastest solution would require a unique id and an index.  That would be:

```
select s.*
from sales s
where not exists (select 1
                  from sales s2
                  where s2.id = s.id and
                        s2.<unique key> <> s.<unique key>
                 );
```

This can take advantage of an index on `(id, <unique key>)`.

Note:  This particular formulation assumes that `category` is never `null`.

Comment: oh, I really like the 2nd solution, thanks! I will test it and check the performance

Comment: @Trefle . . . Be sure you have the recommended index.